# Sed command doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a device with superuser access. I want to delete a line from a text file from my application. This is what I use:

```
outputStream.writeBytes("sed -i '/debug.sf.nobootanimation=1/d' /data/local.prop\n");
```

sed command delete the file completly, not the line with debug. Why? What I need to do to make it work? I want it to delete just the `debug.sf.nobootanimation=1` line.

Comment: What is your outputStream?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
outputStream.writeBytes("sed -i '/debug\\
```

.sf\.nobootanimation\=1/d' /data/local.prop\n");

Comment: Another way? This isn't good, it gives me "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \)".